# Distribution of Beanstalk On Docker via Codepipleline is not complete

Tags: node.js, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I am configuring CI / CD using Codepipeline and Beanstalk On Docker.

It works fine until the Build process of Codepipeline, but Deploy keeps failing.

> The reason for the failure is not exactly known, but the following
>   error occurs. Service:AmazonCloudFormation, Message:Stack named
>   'awseb--stack' aborted operation. Current state:
>   'UPDATE_ROLLBACK_IN_PROGRESS' Reason: The following resource(s) failed
>   to create: [AWSEBUpdateWaitConditionAFyGSI,
>   AWSEBInstanceLaunchWaitConditionaiyqOL].

My Dockerfile and buildspec.yml, and dockerrun.aws.json files are

### Dockerfile

```
FROM node:12.16.3-alpine as tsbuild

RUN mkdir /usr/app
WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY . /usr/app

RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

FROM node:12.16.3-alpine

RUN mkdir /usr/app
WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY --from=tsbuild /usr/app/dist /usr/app
COPY package*.json /usr/app/

RUN npm install -g pm2
RUN npm install

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["npm", "run", "prod"]
```

### buildspec.yml

```
version: 0.2
env:
  variables:
    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: ap-northeast-2
    AWS_EB_DEPLOY_ENV: docker
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      docker: 18
      nodejs: 10
    commands:
      - aws --version
      - $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region ap-northeast-2)
      - npm install
  build:
    commands:
      - docker build -t image .
  post_build:
    commands:
      - docker tag image:latest <ECR_URL>
      - docker <ECR_URL>
```

### Dockerrun.aws.json

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Image": {
    "Name": <ECR_URL>,
    "Update": "true"
  },
  "Ports": [
    {
      "ContainerPort": "8080"
    }],
  "Volumes": [],
  "Logging": "/var/log/nodejs"
}
```

Also, I am using ts-node, but when I open the zip distributed in Beanstalk, I cannot find the dist folder.

I am using BuildArtifacts in CodeDeploy, not SourceArtifacts. Can this be a problem?

I would like to know what i made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me 'Dockerrun.aws.json' is not getting into the source bundle. If it is in the root of the code repo, then please add the following to buildspec.yml:

```
artifacts:
  files:
    -  '**/*'
```